# Webview File Upload Issue in Android

Tags: java, android, file-upload, webview

I am using a code which found on google search for uploading files in android studio webview.

I got two issues.

1) In android version 4.4.2, onclicking the file upload button it triggers the file chooser , but app get closed automatically.

2) in android 5.0.2, it triggers the file chooser dialog, but after selecting the file , it still shows as no file choosen.

what i am doing wrong here..

Here is MainActivity.Java

```
package example.filenewupload;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;



@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;
    protected static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/browse.html");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ),
                        MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView,
                                             ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                                             FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Browser" ),
                        MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Browser");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, i);



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dptechnologysolutions.filenewupload">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The app closes automatically for a reason, it is probably crashing. Anything in Logcat?

Comment: I am not directly connecting my device (android 4.4.2) with android studio, since i dont have a cable with me. I tried building apk, transferred to my phone and tried it. It getting crashed. But in Version 5 it works , but only file selection issue !!!

Comment: Well you are a bit stuck if you don't get the logs. Why don't you make an Android 4.4.2 emulator device? Then you can get the logs. You need the logs to diagnose the error.

Comment: okay let me try on the 4.4.2 part. what about the version 5. ?

Comment: Where does it say no file chosen? Nowhere in your code do you try to say a file was chosen. Is it in the file picker? You need to be really explicit when asking your questions on SO.

Comment: okay to be more clear, the input file type by default it will show Choose File in button and the No file choosen next to the button.

Once we selected the file No File choosen text will go away the selected file name will appear there. in my situation after selecting the file, there is no selected file name appearing